# Change UIView (inside nib) background from other viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Anyone know how to alter a view inside a nib from another viewcontroller? I have a outlet from the view in nib-file to the view class-file and I have `@synthesize` the view-class `.m` file. And then I `#import "InfoView.h"` (which is the view class) the view to the viewcontroller and at last I:

```
    InfoView *infoView; 
    if (infoView == nil) 
    { 
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"infoView" owner:self options:nil]; 
    infoView = [nib objectAtIndex:0]; 
    } 

infoView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:1];"
```

But I can't get the background to change.

Has anyone tried to do something like this before? 
I appreciate any input thank you!

EDIT:
Have addressed the `UIColor` issue but that was not the problem.

Comment: Make sure you linked properly the outlets in your custom view and make sure you have specified the class of the custom view in the xib file

Comment: @danypata Yes have done that

Comment: @PaperThick When you use the method colorWithRed you need to divide to 255.0f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code I have made the demo app for you.
create file `CustomView.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLbl;

@end
```

> CustomView.m. If you are using XIB

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView

@synthesize titleLbl = _titleLbl;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];
        UIView *theEditView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        theEditView.frame = self.bounds;
        [self addSubview: theEditView];
        theEditView = nil;
    }


    return self;
}
```

> Set `fileOwner` of `CustomView.XIB` is CustomView. and connect outlets.
>   Where ever you want to use `CustomView` take a `UIView` object in your `XIB`, and rename `UIView` class with `CustomView`. Create an `IBOutlet` in your `.h` file and connect it with `CustomView` object in `XIB`.
>   Now do this:

```
self.customViewObj.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.customViewObj.titleLbl.text = @"Prateek";
```

In your case your `customview` object is not created. if you print your object it will show you `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `-colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha` wrongly. They expect a float value between 0 and 1. You need to do:

```
infoView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:50.0/255.0 blue:50.0/255.0 alpha:1];"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but Now I tested with a label and I could not change text on it from the viewcontroller so it must be a problem with the linking

Comment: are you sure that infoView is != nil? Where are you adding it as a subview?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the background color.. then do this:

```
infoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:1];
```